# Python Store IP address in a variable

Tags: python, input, ip

I'm new to programming in Python and can't store an IP address in a variable (ip)

```
ip = input("Enter IP address: ")

# 192.168.0.1 (Example)

print ("you entered: "+ip)
```

Im getting an error message and don't know what to do.

Comment: What is the error message? Provide full traceback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you are using Python 2.x.  If so, then [`input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) is evaluating its input as real Python code.

In other words, when you enter `192.168.0.1`, a `SyntaxError` is being raised because the input contains illegal syntax:

```
>>> input()
192.168.0.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    192.168.0.1
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

---

To fix the problem, you need to use [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead:

```
ip = raw_input("Enter IP address: ")
```

Unlike `input`, `raw_input` always returns a string object:

```
>>> raw_input()
192.168.0.1
'192.168.0.1'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks man for quick respone , next time i will provide the whole error message. That was exactly the error message i got too!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to don't worry about `Python 2.x` or `Python 3.x`, use `sys.stdin` for reading from input  and `sys.stdout` for printing to output for that section.

```
import sys

sys.stdout.write("Enter IP address: ")
sys.stdout.flush()
ip = sys.stdin.readline()
print("you entered: " + ip)
```

Output:

```
Enter IP address: 192.168.1.1
you entered: 192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ip = raw_input("Enter Target IP =>")
if ip >0:
    print("=>" + ip )
```

You must add `raw_input` to add whole custom IP address.
If it still shows eror, you may have to convert `ip` to a string.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see this solution here, so posting. Hopefully this helps others.

This solution *will work when run on **both** Python 2.X and 3.X*. I ran into this issue when needing my script to be compatible between both Python versions.

`raw_input()` works on 2.x, throws exception on 3.x

`input()` can't read an ip address formatted input on 2.x (exception), 3.x works

## Solution

```
try:
    ip_address = raw_input('Enter IP Address: ')  
except:
    ip_address = input('Enter IP Address: ')
```

`ip_address` will be a `str` of the entered ip address regardless of the Python version in this solution.

PS: You can check if the entered address is a valid ip address with the following:

```
import re
if not re.match(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', ip_address):
    print('Invalid IP Address')
```